# UL LI horizontal positioned center aligned

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to make something as this [example](http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/) just i need to have text below the image in each li. How can I put text below the image with out floating the image or usign `</br>` because neither of those will work.

Comment: text below the image ? or image below the text ?

Comment: it still wont be below the image, it will be on the right site of the image. I have tried. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried giving the text margin or padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/t66hM/1/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the image have a block display style.

`display: block` will cause the element width to be as wide as its parent, so if you have something inline next to it, that inline element will be forced under it.